# layout_width in table row

Tags: android, xml

i have a TableLayout with multiple rows. The rows may have 2 or 3 elements.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/spielfortsetzung" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/loesung" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

In Android Studio the layouts look correct, but not on my device, when I run the app. There all the layouts just have minimal space for 1-2characters. Also it doesn't use the whole width, but leaves space on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone. I agree that with weight="0.5" it is done better.

My problem however was something different. I load this layout in a Fragment. This only part of a dynamic UI, so not the full screen is filled with this layout. I used null for parent container, but no I use the ViewGroup container I get as a parameter and submit false for attachToParent, otherwise my app would crash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<TableRow
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="@string/spielfortsetzung" />

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="@string/loesung" />
```

//same to other rows , define the weight as a portion .

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the XML the first TableRow probably shows up correctly, the second on you forgot the weightSum for the TableRow, and all two rows are requesting a weight of 1. Add weightSum=2 to the second row should solve your issue.